# Some form data submitted by new users is a duplicate of a value submitted by a previous user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

There's a simple registration form [on this page](http://www.cityofknowledge.co.uk/retreatform.php) which is used to collect details of new registrations. The registration script is quite poorly coded however does very little to manipulate the data:

```
$first_name = stripslashes($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = stripslashes($_POST['last_name']);
$foo = stripslashes($_POST['foo']);
...
$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($first_name);
$last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($last_name);
$foo = mysql_real_escape_string($foo);
...
if(mysql_query(INSERT INTO blessedbirthretreat2015 (first_name, last_name, foo...)
VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$foo'...))) {
}
```

Then an email is sent with a few of the user's details. However, several registrations have been saved using the values from a previous registration, these are received as such in both the email and the table. The table looks like this:

[Link to table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seHuz.png)

As can be seen, entries 12-26 use the same data for the following fields:

- mobile_phone varchar(16)
- email varchar(32)
- address_1 varchar(512)
- post_code varchar(16)
- emergency_name varchar(64)
- emergency_phone varchar(16)
- medical_conditions varchar(512)

The following are not duplicated.

- id int(4)
- first_name varchar(16)
- last_name varchar(16)
- gender varchar(8)
- date_of_birth varchar(16)

The other curiosity I've noticed is that the registration emails were received within 1-2 minutes of each other for all of these users - it is incredibly unlikely that they registered one after another. Any ideas how this might be occurring?

Comment: They've found a way to exploit your script, simple solution: Make email address a unique field and allow one registration per user, before they can have access send a verification email, any fake emails like `aoifnmoasinfofn@fakeemail.com` will be unable to receive such an email, and thus be unable to access your site.

Comment: That's a possibility, but this registration is for an event with a small local charity and all the data looks legitimate, I'm quite sure this is a bug in the code somewhere. Especially since we got a dozen registrations within minutes whereas usually we get perhaps 50 across two months.

Comment: Considering the data is changing so rapidly, I fail to see how this is a bug, if these are legit registrations, then validate that the person is real.

Comment: I had a look through registers for previous events, most of the registrants with duplicated data here have attended in the past, and had applied using unique details in previous years. I plan to rewrite the whole script though, it's a complete mess at the moment, so it warrants fixing anyway. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Insert a secret token into the form and check that secret token in your php script.

Comment: If there are multiple events/sign ups, then have this as a "registration" with a separate table for events (3NF)